# creating a table on the fly, where did it go?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a table, if the name doesn't already exist

```
string sc1 = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME = @name) SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0";
string sc2 = @"CREATE TABLE dbo.Data" + pv.tablecounter + "(testdescription VARCHAR(25), testvalue VARCHAR(5))";

SqlCommand check1 = new SqlCommand(sc1, connection);
check1.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Data" + pv.tablecounter;
SqlCommand check2 = new SqlCommand(sc2, connection);
exists = Convert.ToInt32(chec.ExecuteScalar());

if(exists == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("table exists, will not create new one");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("table wasn't found, creating now");
    check2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

i can verify that this is all "working" (the correct `message` will show, and it will find the newly created table and give me the right message).  My `connection string` works fine

my question is, where did it go?  i can't browse and find it in the server explorer.  this is probably basic but i cannot find any info about it.  I have tried specifying the database

`@"CREATE TABLE testdb.dbo.Data" + pv.tablecounter + "(testdescription VARCHAR(25), testvalue VARCHAR(5))";`

Wth an error that `database testdb does not exist` , even though it's in my `server explorer` and i have been writing to it elsewhere using the same `connection string`

using Visual Studio 2017

thanks

Comment: Have you refreshed the list of tables in SSMS/VS?  Are you dbo?

Comment: yes, and restarted everything, and opened in VS2015 to test.  same results

Comment: If you are viewing it on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you need to go to the Tables node, and call the Refresh option on the left-button menu.

Comment: Does `select * from dbo.Data` throw anything?

Comment: Are you disposing the connection afterwards? Is there a transaction that needs to be completed?

Comment: You might use the Profiler to monitor, which statements are passed over to SQL Server. Quite often one works with a different server/database than you think you do...

Comment: i'm in a using block.  there was a lot disaster in my block for copypasta so i typed out the relevant stuff.  testing the other comments now

Comment: @AlexK. it throws an error `invalid object name`

Comment: trying the Profiler now, that is a bit beyond my experience level but it's good to learn!

Comment: Are you sure, that your "connection" and the connection you use in VS for checking point to the same DB? Furthermore, I would strongly recommend to put the schema name in the "if exists" check as well - experienced lot's of problems in the past when a table with same name existed in another schema.

Comment: found the tables!  they are in my bin (debug) folder.  i am now figuring out why (and more importantly, how to make VS look somewhere else)  thanks for the help everyone.